# QT Quick sending data from C++ to QML when new screen is launch

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick

I am new to QT Quick and QML.
I am building an application in QT Quick QML and C++ for Linux.
I am using StackView for navigation between QML pages and C++ Classes registered as `qmlregistertype`, these classes are accessed from QML for getting states and data.

What I want is,
Every time a new screen is launched I want to get some states/data from cloud server and then update the UI with latest states/data as received from cloud server. Will it be possible to send some JSON string from CPP to QML and then QML parses this data and updates the UI accordingly? How to implement this in C++ and QML? Will it be same as signal slots?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in an unrelated question I submitted, I did something similar. See this [demo app to expose c++ data to qml to draw charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61942795/how-to-set-the-range-of-a-barcategoryaxis-in-a-qml-bar-chart)

The method I chose is to expose my C++ class *chartdata* using `setContextProperty("chartdata",chartdata)` in the main.cpp.  Then the C++ function to generate the data can be called from QML using a signal and `chartdata.generateData()`

Answer (score 0):

You have many different ways to do this.
You can use [signals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html), [Q_PROPERTY](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html) or even expose [JSON object](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html) to QML.