# How to set the range of a BarCategoryAxis in a QML bar chart?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am generating data in C++ (*chartdata* class) and then using it as input to QML charts (*main.qml*). However, for some reason, the BarCategoryAxis which corresponds to the AxisX is not showing the right range, therefore I only see a fraction of the categories. I have tried using min and max properties in the BarCategoryAxis object, but the categories are strings, so there is no min/max. I attach a screenshot of the window for clarity.

The lower chart of the window shows the bar chart, it can be seen that only 4 categories are visible. But 8 categories are generated by the C++ class, with values from 1 to 15

[image]

Please find below the relevant files :

.pro file

```
QT += quick core gui charts
CONFIG += c++11
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
SOURCES += \
    chartdata.cpp \
    main.cpp
RESOURCES += qml.qrc
# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =
# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =
# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
HEADERS += \
chartdata.h
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include<QQmlContext>
#include"chartdata.h"

QT_CHARTS_USE_NAMESPACE

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    ChartData* chartdata = new ChartData();
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    QQmlContext * context = engine.rootContext();
    context->setContextProperty("chartdata",chartdata);

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                 &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
         if (!obj && url == objUrl)
        QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
          }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);
   return app.exec();
 }
```

chartdata.h

```
#ifndef CHARTDATA_H
#define CHARTDATA_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtCharts/QLineSeries>
#include<QtCharts/QBarSeries>
#include<QDate>

QT_CHARTS_USE_NAMESPACE

class ChartData : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ChartData();
public slots:
    void setLineSeries(QLineSeries* lineSeries);
    void setBarSeries(QBarSeries* barSeries);
    void generateData();

signals:
    void dataGenerated();

private:
    QVector<QDateTime> m_dates;
    QVector<double> m_data1;
    QStringList m_categories;
    QVector<int> m_data2;
};

#endif // CHARTDATA_H
```

chartdata.cpp

```
#include "chartdata.h"
#include<QtMath>
#include <QtCharts/QBarSet>

ChartData::ChartData()
{

}

void ChartData::setLineSeries(QLineSeries *lineSeries)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_data1.size(); i++) {
        lineSeries->append(m_dates[i].toMSecsSinceEpoch(),m_data1[i]);
    }
}

void ChartData::setBarSeries(QBarSeries *barSeries)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_data2.size(); i++) {
        QBarSet *set = new QBarSet(m_categories[i]);
        *set << m_data2[i];
        barSeries->append(set);
    }
}

void ChartData::generateData()
{
    //generate data for line series
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        m_dates.append(QDateTime::fromString("2020/1/"+QString::number(i), "yyyy/M/d"));
        m_data1.append(qCos(0.5*i));
    }

    //generate data for bar series
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        m_categories.append("Category_" + QString::number(i));
        m_data2.append(2*i+1);
    }

    if (m_dates.size() > 0){
        emit dataGenerated();
    }
}
```

main.qml. The C++ data is generated in the onCompleted block at the beginning, and then called in the charts using the functions addLineSeries() and addBarSeries().

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtCharts 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Component.onCompleted: {
     chartdata.generateData()
    }

    Connections{
        target: chartdata
        onDataGenerated: {
            addLineSeries()
            addBarSeries()
        }
    }

    ColumnLayout{
        id:buttonLayout
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 20

        ChartView {
            id:lineSeriesChart
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            antialiasing: true

            DateTimeAxis {
                id:xTime
                format: "dd MM yyyy"
                tickCount: 5
                min: new Date(2019,12,1)
                max: new Date(2020,1,1)
            }

            ValueAxis {
                id:yValues
                min:-1
                max:1
            }
        }

        ChartView {
            id: barSeriesChart
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            antialiasing: true
            legend.alignment: Qt.AlignBottom

            BarCategoryAxis {
                id: myCategories
            }

            ValueAxis{
                id: myBarValues
                min: -10
                max: 10
            }
        }
    }

    function addLineSeries()
    {
        var mySeries = lineSeriesChart.createSeries(ChartView.SeriesTypeLine, "my line series", xTime, yValues);
        chartdata.setLineSeries(mySeries)
    }

    function addBarSeries()
    {
        var mySeries = barSeriesChart.createSeries(ChartView.SeriesTypeBar,"my bar series", myCategories, myBarValues)
        chartdata.setBarSeries(mySeries)
        mySeries.barWidth = 0.1
    }
}
```